# What is the strongest filament type?

Tags: filament, filament-choice

I'm looking for a filament that is strong, doesn't crack and doesn't break easily and is impact resistant. I'm currently using PLA and it's strong, but, I'm looking for something that doesn't snap or break when dropped.

Comment: It would help if you indicated what application you are considering. That will inform any recommendations.

Comment: "strong" does not mean much by itself and then you asked about cracking but also breaking when hit. The question is too broad and has no definite answer. Provide a specific use case, otherwise we cannot answer.

Answer (score 3):

PEEK may well be the strongest filament out there (and it has other interesting properties to recommend it), but it is very difficult to print and requires a printer designed to operate at high temperatures. If you are still using PLA, your next port of call should be PETG. It is a lot stronger than PLA (although it will shatter if hit hard enough) and it is almost as easy to print. It also gives off hardly any fumes and it can be printed without an enclosure.

Comment: PLA (pure, not modified with softeners) is far stronger than PETG, especially layer bonding. The reasons for using PETG are heat resistance and resistance to deterioration from elements. Not strength.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE the question is also about impact resistance and PETG is better than PLA for that. The problem is that the question is broad and poor...

Answer (score 3):

ABS is less brittle compared to PLA.

Strength and impact resistance are not the same.  For the same Volume and Shape, I get more tensile strength (can apply a larger force without breaking) from steel than rubber.  I can however pound the rubber with a hammer many more times than the steel before I break it.

When it comes to impact (finite energy but potentially extremely large forces), general rule is: that which does not bend shall break.  Materials and shapes that can bend to help dissipate that energy will help against impact.  Outright strength, on the other hand, often is fairly rigid.

When I need both, I'll depend on a strength bearing part and a soft coating for impact.  Works for bony animals; works for parts.

Comment: PLA also gets more brittle as it absorbs moisture.